# Python running in AWS Lamda getting "xxxx not defined" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple script to update a value in DynamoDB, and then give me back the updated value. If I run the script in VSCode, talking to AWS, it works fine - no errors.  But when I format it for Lambda, I get an error.

**VSCode**

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('Visitors')

response = table.update_item(
    Key={'ID': 0},
    UpdateExpression="ADD #ct :increment",
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#ct': 'visitorcount'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':increment': 1},

    ReturnValues = "UPDATED_NEW"
    
)
visitorCount = int(response["Attributes"]["visitorcount"])
print('visitorCount obtained from table = ' + str(visitorCount))
```

**Lambda**

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('Visitors')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dbresponse = table.update_item(
        Key={'ID': 0},
        UpdateExpression="ADD #ct :increment",
        ExpressionAttributeNames={'#ct': 'visitorcount'},
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':increment': 1},

    ReturnValues = "UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    
visitorCount = int(dbresponse["Attributes"]["visitorcount"])
print('visitorCount obtained from table = ' + str(visitorCount))
```

**Lambda error when testing**

Test Event Name
mycodetest

```
Response
{
  *"errorMessage": "name 'dbresponse' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",*
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py\", line 127, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1030, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1007, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 680, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 850, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  *File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in <module>\n    visitorCount = int(dbresponse[\"Attributes\"][\"visitorcount\"])\n"*
```

I've Googled to no avail, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's something small, but not being a programmer, finding this hurdle very difficult to overcome.

Comment: Your code indent is wrong. I assume the last 2 lines must be inside function context.

Comment: Dang it! You're right - just moving them over fixed the problem.  You're a genius! Thank you so much, I've been trying to figure that out for hours.  Now on to the next phase adn the next problem. :-)